# php cURL retrieve PDF from javascript form function

Tags: php, forms, curl

Could you have a look at this page: http://apps.humana.com/tad/tad_new/Search.aspx?sortfield=name&policyType=medical

I am trying to figure out the approach I could take with cURL to download the PDF's behind each link on that page.

I've tried submitting the page's main form with the following cURL code:

I am assuming that the 'VIEWSTATE' variable being 90000 characters long is going to be a problem, although I'm hoping not. **

```
$post_vars = array(
'__EVENTTARGET' => 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MentorResultsGridView$ctl02$HrefLink',
'EVENTARGUMENT' => '',
'VIEWSTATE' => '**A STRING THAT IS 90000 characters long!!!**',
'submitted' => 'submitted',
'__SCROLLPOSITIONX', '0',
'__SCROLLPOSITIONY', '0',
'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MentorResultsGridView$ctl02$NewHiddenField', 'Revised'
);

$form_url = 'http://apps.humana.com/tad/tad_new/Search.aspx?sortfield=name&policyType=medical';

$cookie = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $form_url);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_vars);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $output;
```

Comment: Probably your problem is on your webservice. Curl's doesn't define the type of return.

Comment: That site uses Javascript to perform the downloads. You need to examine the Javascript and figure out what URLs it's downloading from. Then you have to scrape the calls and perform analogous transformations. There's no built-in functions for this, you need to work it all out.

Comment: @Guerra - I don't understand what you mean by this ...

Comment: Normaly you open page in browser and click some link, link run script in javascript, this script generate _real_ link to file and send this file to you. You have to get this script (javascript), analyze how it works and make the same in your PHP script. By the way: I download one file (in Firefox) and now I know _real_ link to this file http://dctm.humana.com/Mentor/Web/v.aspx?objectID=09000929812a0616&searchID=f342e0ef-2ab8-43a7-9fe0-fd55f35f9015&dl=1

Comment: @Furas - Actually, I think just gathering the direct links to the pdf's I need is going to be much easier than wasting my time combing through the large javascript maze.  Thank you!

Comment: I analyze _real_ link and link on the page and I think that there is easier way. You can use real link from my previous comment and change `objecID` number to get others files. (Cut off `searchID`, it doesn't matter.). You can find `objectID` number on your page in link tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links on page looks like this (I leave only important part):

```
<a ... name="09000929812a0616" ... >
```

use this `name` as `objectID` in this address to get file:

```
http://dctm.humana.com/Mentor/Web/v.aspx?dl=1&objectID=09000929812a0616
```